# Vala program with protocol-buffers "proto3" support

Tags: vala

I need to implement Google's protocol-buffer support in several of my Vala programs. I was lucky enough to find [Robert Ancell's blog](http://bobthegnome.blogspot.com/2013/01/vala-support-for-protocol-buffers.html) to learn from, kudos Bob. This approach works great between the test programs I have written. It appears however to only support syntax="proto2". I need to interface with other systems that only support syntax="proto3" formats.

Are there any other alternative methods/libraries for Vala with proto3 support?

Comment: Are proto2 and proto3 binary incompatible or is it just the syntax of the proto files that was changed? If binary compatibility is still there you could just translate the file from proto3 to proto2. Of course that is not very satisfying, but it might work.